# Is there a source where Emuna and Bitachon are described as separate ideas?

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, faith-bitachon-emunah, chazon-ish

In the sefer [Emuna UBitachon](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%98%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9F_(%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8)), the [Chazon Ish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avrohom_Yeshaya_Karelitz) popularized the idea that Emuna and Bitachon are really two parts of one idea, one being the belief in the idea, and one being the idea believed in.

Is there anyone past or present who explicitly says the opposite, that Emuna and Bitachon are rather two completely separate ideas?

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/265395/jewish/Bitachon-Reflections-on-Trust.htm ; http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1405289/jewish/Bitachon.htm

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48666

Answer (score 3):

See this [translation of a talk of the Lubavitcher Rebbe](http://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/2296503/jewish/Faith-and-Trust.htm) about the difference between Emunah and Bitachon:

An excerpt from there about Bitachon:

> Trust, by contrast, implies not only that a person believes that his sustenance comes from G‑d, but also that we rely on Him, with absolute certainty, to provide it.

An excerpt about Emunah ([footnote 12](http://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/2296503/jewish/Faith-and-Trust.htm#footnote12a2296503)):

> A person’s emunah is not necessarily integrated and internalized to the point that it translates into actual practice. Instead, it can remain a mere outsider, a makkif. Thus, for example, it is possible that before breaking intoa house, a thief will cry out to G‑d, [Who forbids burglary,] and ask Him to prosper his efforts! (See Berachos 63a, as cited in Ein Yaakov.) Such a self-contradiction is not possible with regard to bitachon.

Answer (score 1):

See [2nd page of this article](http://www.prayingwithfire.org/images/Newsletter165.pdf), though, the whole article is worth reading. Excerpt:

> What is the difference between emunah and bitachon? They both involve
>   the belief that G-d alone brought into being all existence and that He
>   single-handedly runs the world. However, bitochon, trusting Hashem
>   with one’s life, only arises out of a deeply ingrained sense of
>   emunah.
>
> The Ramban (Kisvei Ramban, [Sefer HaEmunah U’Bitachon, Ch. 1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43683&pgnum=3)) explains:
>   “Emunah is like a tree and bitachon is similar to the fruit. The fruit
>   is a sign of the tree [that it exists]. However, the tree is not a
>   sign of the fruit since there are trees that do not bear fruit. Yet,
>   there is no fruit without a tree.”

I don't have access to Ramba"n, currently, to review his entire statement. But, it seems, that he explains them as separate concepts.

Comment: That sounds to me like a raya listor!:) He is also saying they are part of the same process.

Comment: (*raya listor* = opposite proof. @user6591 watch your language :P )

Comment: @Shokhet is the term not applicable?

Comment: It's quoting the Ramban, not the 'Ramba"m', but actually the Ramban probably didn't write Sefer HaEmunah U'Bitachon anyway

Comment: @user6591 No, that's not what I meant.....I just meant to say that you can't expect everybody to understand phrases like that.

Comment: @Shokhet Oh gosh. You know i actually translated it and it lost all its flavor! I forgot i need to watch my back. You are always lurking, waiting, to pounce and translate!

Comment: @user6591 Yup. That's what I'm here for ;)

Answer (score 1):

the first two gates of chovos halevavos have the theme of emuna.

the third has the theme of the duty of serving God

the fourth deals with bitachon, trusting in God like a slave trusts in his master for providing his needs.

so it seems they are separate themes, but not completely. it is a kind of build up.

you cannot have trust without faith, and likewise your trust is only as strong as your faith.

but you can have faith without trust. One can know and believe that God exists but still not trust that God is taking care of him, for that He must study God's system of hashgacha (providence) and be doing God's will, etc. as explained there.